# How can I factor multiples function that gets their result process by another function?

Tags: refactoring, ocaml

I would like to factorize this code :

```ml
(* This function is applied to the result of functions below *)
let manage_result r s =
    match r with
    | Error ( `Msg e ) ->  Tsdl.Sdl.log s e;exit 1
    | Ok a -> a

(* Examples of function I want to factorize, let's call them f_functions, f for factorize *)
let init () =
    let flag = Tsdl.Sdl.Init.everything in
    let result = Tsdl.Sdl.init flag in 
    manage_result result "Init error : %s"

let create_window title w h =
    let flag = Tsdl.Sdl.Window.windowed in
    let result = Tsdl.Sdl.create_window title ~w:w ~h:h flag in
    manage_result result "Create window error : %s"

let get_window_surface window = 
    let result = Tsdl.Sdl.get_window_surface window in
    manage_result result "Get window surface error : %s"
```

As you can see, the two last lines of all of these f_functions are very similar. I would like to make a function that takes as argument a function ( for example, if I wanted to factorize init, the function passed as a parameter would be `Tsdl.Sdl.init`) and return a function that return the return value of function passed as an argument AND processed through `manage_result`.

The difficulty is that I don't know how many argument can the f_functions take.

Any other recommendations is appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: This kind of question is more suited for [codereview.se]

Answer (score 0):

A potential solution might be to use the pipe operator rather than naming the intermediary result

```
let on_error s r = manage_result r s
let create_window title w h =
    let flag = Tsdl.Sdl.Window.windowed in
    Tsdl.Sdl.create_window title ~w:w ~h:h flag
    |> on_error "Create window error : %s"
```

Going one step further, we could define a custom operator for the error handling

```
let ( <!> ) = manage_result
```

which may make your definition lightweight enough

```
let create_window title w h =
    let flag = Tsdl.Sdl.Window.windowed in
    Tsdl.Sdl.create_window title ~w:w ~h:h flag
    <!> "Create window error : %s"
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. however, i think the problem still persists, i don't want to define a function of each function in the library that i'm using, for example, i want to be able to do something like this `(some_magic Sdl.init) flag` or `(some_magic Sdl.create_window) title x y w h flag`

Comment: What difference do you see between `(magic "Error %s" init" init) flag` and `init flag <!> "Error %s"`? Except the fact that the latter is shorter (and possible)? Note that there are alternative encodings but there are much more complicated and they would probably end up being  even more verbose.

Comment: the difference is that `init flag <!> "Error %s"` is inside `create_window` whereas `(magic "error %s init" init) flag` is at the top level, in a `main` for example. i would like to avoid defining new function for each function in `Sdl` that requires their result to be processed through `manage_result`. instead, I would like a function that take these `Sdl` function, and return a new function that takes the same arguments as these `Sdl` function but the results from these function would already be processed through `manage_result`. However I feel like there's a misunderstanding

Comment: Indeed, I don't follow you. You may want to write some example of what you would want (in fantasy syntax if needed).

Comment: actually, this was useless. i could've just made a function that takes the result of functions in the `Sdl` module and manage the result from there, the difference with the magic function slim and not much shorter `(magic Sdl.init) flag` VS `manage_result (Sdl.init flag)` I apologize